# Using CXF ClientBUilder, how to unmarshal post response parameters into Java class

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I'm using CXF ClientBuilder to send POST data to a REST service.  The response I get back looks like this right now:

```
errorCode=206&errorMessage=blah+blah
```

I want to unmarshal this into fields in a POJO.

The following code block illustrates what I have right now:

```
public void validateToken(String token) {
    WebTarget   target  = client.target(getHostPort()).path(getPath());
    Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Form  form    = new Form();
    form.param("TokenID", token);
    Response  postResponse    = request.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
    System.out.println("postResponse[" + postResponse + "]");
    System.out.println("response.text[" + postResponse.readEntity(String.class) + "]");
//      CodeAndMessage    codeAndMessage  = request.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), CodeAndMessage.class);
//      System.out.println("codeAndMessage[" + codeAndMessage + "]");
}

public static class CodeAndMessage {
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public String getErrorCode() { return errorCode; }
    public String getErrorMessage() { return errorMessage; }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) { this.errorCode = errorCode; }
    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) { this.errorMessage = errorMessage; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).
                append("errorCode", getErrorCode()).
                append("errorMessage", getErrorMessage()).
                build();
    }
}
```

As written right now, I get the response as I originally described.  I'm trying to figure out some variation of those last commented-out lines to replace the first "request.post()" and the two following lines, to get the result I'm looking for.

**Update**:

I did find at least one way to do this, but I don't know if it's the best way.

```
    Form  responseForm    = request.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), Form.class);
    System.out.println("responseForm[" + responseForm + "] map[" + responseForm.asMap() + "]");
    return new CodeAndMessage().
                errorCode(responseForm.asMap().getFirst("errorCode")).
                errorMessage(responseForm.asMap().getFirst("errorMessage"));
```

The key was using the Form object for the response type.  With this solution, I still have to reference the field names.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Update**:

I would guess that a cleaner solution would require implementing a MessageBodyReader for this CodeAndMessage class, but I'm not sure yet how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My MessageBodyReader implementation looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider;

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public class StuffResponseReader  implements MessageBodyReader<StuffResponse> {

    private FormEncodingProvider<Form> formProvider = new FormEncodingProvider<>();

    private static final String PROP_ERROR_CODE                 = "errorCode";
    private static final String PROP_ERROR_DESCRIPTION          = "errorMessage";
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type.isAssignableFrom(StuffResponse.class);
    }

    @Override
    public StuffResponse readFrom(Class<StuffResponse> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
            MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Form    form    = formProvider.readFrom(Form.class, Form.class, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> data = form.asMap();
        return new StuffResponse().
                errorCode(data.getFirst(PROP_ERROR_CODE)).
                errorDescription(data.getFirst(PROP_ERROR_DESCRIPTION)).
                ...;
    }
}
```

When creating the ClientBuilder, I register the MBR like this:

```
ClientBuilder   builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(StuffResponseReader.class);
```